# How do I copy an array so I can remove elements from the copy in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

I am working with a copy of an array so I can modify it.  Sample is

```
var x:[1..4] int = [1,2,3,4];
writeln(x);
x.remove(3);
writeln(x);

var y = x;
writeln(y);
y.remove(2);
writeln(y);
```

The last line, however, gives me

```
error: halt reached - cannot call remove on an array defined over a domain with multiple arrays
```

So what is the correct method to copy and allow edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```
var y = x;
```

you're getting a new array `y` whose domain (index set) is the same as `x`'s.  That is, this declaration would be similar to saying:

```
var D = {1..4};      // create a domain
var x, y: [D] int;   // create two arrays that share that domain
```

As the error message suggests, Chapel does not permit directly resizing an array that shares its domain with another array because, if it did, removing an element from `y` would also cause that element to be removed from `x` which we believe would be far too subtle and surprising to support.

So in order to create a copy of `x` that is modifiable, you'll want to declare `y` in a way that gives it its own individual domain.  The simplest way to do this for your specific program would be as follows:

```
var y: [1..3] int = x;
```

You could also write it a bit more flexibly as:

```
var y: [1..x.size] int = x;
```

or even:

```
var y: [1..x.size] x.eltType = x;
```

Since each of these declarations results in `y` getting its own unique domain, it can be modified independently of `x`.

Comment: I've tried `var y: [x.domain] x.eltType = x;` and `var y: x.type = x;`, but both of them resulted in the same error as `var y = x;`. So is it OK to understand that the former two also share the domain of x? (Btw, `var D = x.domain; var y: [D] x.eltType = x;` worked for me, so this may be convenient to preserve bounds?) (It might also be convenient if a method like `var y = copy( x );` exists... :-)

Comment: @roygbiv: You're correct that `x.domain` gives a reference to `x`'s domain, so will share it.  And that `x.type` gives `x`'s type which includes its domain, so those are two other ways of sharing a domain, by intention.  Your `D` declaration creates a new domain that takes its value from another, which is why it works.  My thinking about a copy method was that maybe we should have domains support one so you could write `var y: [x.domain.copy()] x.eltType = x;`  I'm not opposed to a `copy()` method/function for arrays, but think it's ambiguous whether it'd naturally copy the domain or not...